# HTML - Run Command Line?

Tags: html, forms, input, terminal, command

Been doing some searching but can't really find what I need, I have a HTML file and need the "Submit" button to take some date and run a command line on our macs? This is just an internal app that will be kept on-site.

So the form.html has an input box for "Username" and then box then has a section for "Location" which is a drop down list.

Then a submit button

What I want to try and do is take the selections and run a command line such as -

```
sudo jamf policy --set Username "Inputted text here"
sudo jamf policy --set Location "Selected drop down"
```

Then I want it to close the form.html and load index.html? On "Submit"

Is what I want to happen even possible? If not I will try find alternatives. Ideal though needs to be html based.

Really appreciate any help with this, my coding level is quite minimum so take it easy!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run a command line with just HTML. You need JavaScript inside of your html file to do it. HTML is not a programming language but a markup language designed for the structure of text formatting. You should add JavaScript code inside of your html file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
your javascript code
</script>
```

Then, call the function you wrote above like this:

```
<form onsubmit="functionName()">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```